# What is the fastest way to kill my family?

Tags: papers-please

There is an ending in which your family dies. I want to get this ending as fast as possible. Can I just turn heating off and not buy food, or will I die myself?

Comment: ...I'm not familiar with this game. You *are* talking about a game, right?

Comment: yes I'm talking about the game, reads a bit psycho now you mention it :D Edited the text a bit.

Comment: As @RavenDreamer 's hand hovers over his phone lol

Comment: 10/10 misleading title, have an upvote.

Comment: Either your family is very unlucky to have you, or you are to have them. I can't quite decide... ;)

Comment: another one for the collection of strange titles

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fastest way is to not pay for food, heat or medicine (but pay the rent!).

You yourself won't be affected, but your family will.

Comment: ok, I'll test this when I get home.

Comment: Pay the rent is mandatory, you can't choose not to pay it.

Comment: On the bright side, you save lots of money!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot die from cold or hunger in Papers, Please. Only your family members can.

When you don't pay the heating or food bills, your family members get cold and/or hungry. This can cause them to get sick, prompting you to buy medicine for them. If you don't, they will get very sick and die.

If you just want to kill them all, never pay the heating or for food. It will only take a few days. If all your family members die, the game ends.

Comment: The earliest I have made (and provble) is on day 5.