# Without spoilers, are any spells permanently missable?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I got to a part of the story where it seems that I've missed some spells. I do not want to get spoiled (nor do I want to spoil other players) and so I'd like to know, without spoilers (or with spoilers properly tagged), if any spells are permanently missable, or if I can learn some spells in any alternative ways.

Comment: o/ I edited the title & post a little bit; please feel free to revert or further adjust it as you see fit :)

Comment: There are some you can choose not to learn. You have to go quite a long way in to the game to learn all the spells.

Comment: I feel like the title would gain clarity by mentioning the game. It's unclear which game is being asked about in the Hot Network Questions section.

Comment: @Clockwork [Oh](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) yeah, [it's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167223/one-of-my-cooks-died-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-corpse) better if we [add](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/my-children-are-useless-what-should-i-do) some game [title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162789/how-do-i-lick-a-plane) at some [point](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139127/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-kill-my-family)?

Comment: @Skye-AT Well, yeah, from my point of view, the titles on all these questions are unclear. But if the community believes otherwise, it's fine by me I guess.

Comment: @Clockwork Look at the edit history :)

Comment: I did indeed notice that the name was removed.

Comment: @Clockwork sorry for the late reply; I never got a notification and happened to stumble on this again (because I wanted to see the answer for my playthrough! lol). I was probably a bit overzealous here: I rewrote the title entirely from what I gathered to be the intention, and honestly forgot the game name was explicitly mentioned originally -- I just rewrote without the name by habit. The convention on Arqade is [not to include the game name](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11398/), but we sometimes disambiguate when very ambiguous or for HNQ -- which it did become sometime post-edit!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to my information there are three missable spells.

There is a time during the main quests where you can still learn two of these if you've chosen before not to learn them.
This is only available if you don't progress the main story too much after this point.

> Imperio and Crucio can be learned for a while afterwards by talking to Sebastian in the Undercroft. This does not apply to Avada Kedavra.

Comment: So the short answer to my question is `yes`? for the one you mention in the end?

Comment: Correct @h0ch5tr4355

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning Alohomora's Lv2/3. If you didn't choose to pick up Demiguise moons and bring that to Gladwin Moon, you won't be able to learn them - in other words, missable. Not the entire spell, but still.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. Yes @Skye-AT but you are able to get them anytime if you decide to I think.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Correct, I guess I missed your word "permanently", sorry for that.

Comment: @Skye-AT This word wasn't there at first; Schism thankfully added it :P

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** - there are (up to) three spells that can be come permanently unavailable to you if you haven't chosen to learn them and then make a certain choice in-game that leads to the character who teaches you them being unavailable (in deference to the no-spoilers request I won't mention which spells, character or choice but it should be obvious once you get there). Choosing the other option means the spells remain available for you to learn at any point - including after the end of the main story missions are completed.

For those who are concerned with achievement hunting these spells **don't** count for the "Learn all spells" achievement/trophy, so you can't lock yourself out of that.

Comment: Nice for mentioning the achivement.